# How to deal with several keyboard layouts when accessing a remote server?

Tags: vimrc, keyboard-layout

I am using two different keyboard layouts (depending on the computer I use) on the same server (one being AZERTY, the other QWERTY).

I would like to have "conditional" mapping options in my .vimrc file, depending on my layout, something like :

```
if (keyboard_layout == QWERTY)
    nnoremap : ;
    nnoremap ; :
elseif (keyboard_layout == AZERTY)
    inoremap :w <Esc>:w<Return>
endif
```

Is it possible ? Or is there a "workaround" not too heavy ?

(sorry for the syntax, I haven't coded much .vimrc files yet)

**Edit**

User @statox gave a very complete [answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/7414/7128)  based on another question asked, I could not test it because I am not 'root' user on the server I'm working on.

I found another way through defining a function, that I [posted as answer here](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/7416/7128).

Comment: Depending on your system you probably have an environment variable or a configuration file which contains your current layout. You could read it from your `.vimrc` and create a condition on it. The problem is that it might be a problem to make this code portable since (as far as I know) not all the distributions keep this information in the same place.

Comment: For the users coming to this question I think OP solved his problem by asking [this other question](http://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/7399/extract-the-result-of-a-shell-command-to-a-variable-in-a-vimrc-file)

Comment: I tried to, but in the end it didn't solve my problem : the $LANG variable does not contain the keyboard layout.
In the end I built a function I have to call if I want to change my mappings.

Comment: What system do you use? Sometimes it is in a configuration file instead of a variable.

Comment: @statox : I use a CentOS Linux or a MacOS X, but I always ssh to the server on which I'm working

Comment: Maybe you could configure each of your machine to send a variable containing the layout (define it manually with [that for example](http://superuser.com/a/702751/386795) ) then on the server you should be able to read the variable you send with the help of your other question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not  use any "environment" variable, but I coded a function that I call in the .vimrc file :

```
" The function in my .vimrc file :
function! Kbdmodes(lang)
   if a:lang=='en'
      imap <akey> <anotherkey>
   elseif a:lang=='fr'
      imap <yetanotherkey> <iamthefourthkey>
   endif
endfunction

let lang='en'
call Kbdmodes(lang)
```

So far it seems to work. By default, upon starting, vim loads my 'qwerty' (english) bindings ; then if I do `:call Kbdmodes('fr')` in normal mode, it switches the bindings to my 'azerty' (french) ones.

I hope this can be useful to anybody !

Answer (score 2):

What I would recommend is the following:

- First on your local machine set an environment variable manually containing your layout:

  ```
  export LAYOUT=AZERTY
  ```
- Then configure ssh to receive this environment variable (Thanks to [this question](https://superuser.com/a/702751/386795) ):

  To do so use the `~/.ssh/config` file and the `SendEnv` command. A very basic example would be:

  ```
  Host server
      HostName dev.example.com
      SendEnc LAYOUT
  ```

  you can then ssh to your server with `ssh server`. (There a lot of documentation of ssh config, you can do a lot of stuff with that).
- You also have to configure the server to accept this new variable: In `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` add the following line (as root):

  ```
  AcceptEnv LAYOUT
  ```
- Finnaly on the server side you can use the answer to [this question](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/7399/1841) to read your variable and make your mappings accordingly:

  ```
  if $LAYOUT == 'AZERTY'
  …
  endif
  ```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed proposition -- one problem though : I am not (and will never be) root on the server I'm using. 

Hence I wrote a function in my .vimrc Kbdmodes(lang), where 'lang' can be 'qwerty', 'azerty'. My problem is now to call it "automatically" when vim starts... I'll probably ask a new question if I can't figure it out.