# Extract the result of a shell command to a variable in a .vimrc file?

Tags: vimscript, external-command

In my `.vimrc` file, I would like to store in a variable the result of an external command, in my case:

```
$ echo $LANG
```

So that my `.vimrc` file would have :

```
let language = output(!echo $LANG)
if language == 'en'
   nnoremap <somekey> <ohanotherkey!>
end if
```

So far I couldn't find how to do it. I've found that in command mode, `:read !echo $LANG`  would insert in my current file the content I am looking for. But I don't know how to write it down in a `.vimrc` file.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You can do this with the `system` function:

```
let language = system('echo $LANG')
```

Bonus point: if your output is a list, you can use the `systemlist` instead to get back a list. e.g.

```
let files = systemlist('ls')
" ['bin', 'dev', ... ]
```

**ref:** [`:h system`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#system%28%29)

Answer (score 17):

If `LANG` is an environment variable you can just do:

```
let language = $LANG
```

Or, even simpler:

```
if $LANG == 'en'
…
endif
```

Comment: This does not exactly answer my too general question... but is even better ! Thanks.