# How to get put the result of a shell command in a variable?

Tags: vimrc, microsoft-windows

I would like to capture the result of a shell command into a vim variable inside of my vimrc file.

I tried using `let myvar = system("DIR")` however it seems to crash vim when I put it in my vimrc file. I launch vim and then it just returns immediately without any error message.

So instead I was wondering if I can do something like `let exe_path = <expr> :!pwd` ? This is obviously the wrong way to do it so I was wondering if something like that is possible?

Comment: the suggested `system()` command should work. Questions is, what you mean with it is crashing vim. That should not happen.

Comment: `let myvar = system('pwd')` is the way to go as described in [this duplicate question](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/7399/1841) on my system it works fine. I think you used the wrong tag and meant `microsoft-windows` so are you sure your Windows shell supports `pwd` (it's been a long time since I haven't used a windows shell so I don't remember if it's supported) maybe you should try with another command ?

Comment: `system()` definitely is the function you're looking for; rather than asking for an alternative, please post more details about that "crash".

Comment: @IngoKarkat I tried doing `let myvar = system("DIR")` while vim was running, and it works well. The problem is when I put that same line inside of my vimrc file. What happens when I reload vim is that it simply shuts down immediately. I enter `vim.exe` then press enter and the console simply returns back right away without any error message.

Comment: As Christian mentioned, that should not happen. On the other hand, invoking an external command during startup would be bad for startup time (especially on Windows), anyway. Can't you do this lazily, on demand? You could also try to execute this on `:autocmd VimEnter * let myvar = system('pwd')`; it's still on startup, but at the end of it.

Comment: If the only thing is to get the curdir then `let myvar = getcwd()` makes more sense than `system()`.

Comment: @IngoKarkat That autocmd works well, I can accept that as an answer if you wanna post it :)

Comment: Ah great that this already solves your problem (but really think hard whether a more lazy approach wouldn't be possible)! I've added an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`system()`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#system%28%29) is the right function; it *should* work fine also inside `~/.vimrc`, but is best avoided as each external command delays Vim's startup and makes the user wait.

Ideally, you'll be able to only invoke the external command once it's required for a user interaction (i.e. *lazily*) - and then cache the information in case it's needed again.

If you absolutely need the information on startup already, and to work around your problem, you can hook into the [`VimEnter`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/autocmd.txt.html#VimEnter) event that is fired at the *end* of initialization:

```
:autocmd VimEnter * let myvar = system('pwd')
```

<sup>The `pwd` is only an example; you'd better use the built-in [`getcwd()`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#getcwd%28%29) instead.</sup>